# Get data from an http source onto an https one

Tags: reactjs, http, https, axios

So I've deployed a project (Used framework is ReactJS) to Heroku, and the given URL uses the HTTPS protocol. The problem which I've met with is that the source where the data is got from, uses an HTTP protocol, thus this error is returned...

[image]

> Here's is the code responsible for getting the data

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://api.decoprim.md/v1/items?key=3VG8BizGax',
  });

export function getProducts() {
    return api.get().then(response => response.data.data);
}
```

Comment: the server don't have a valid ssl certificate. Did you already checked it?

Comment: You can't fetch insecure (http) resources from a secure (https) origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is blocking your requests, you should be using https for all of the resources if page is loading over https but if you can't change that, you can bypass it with 3rd party services like:

1. CORS Anywhere: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
2. All Origins: http://allorigins.me/
3. Any origin: http://anyorigin.com/

Example base url:

```
https://allorigins.me/get?url=http%3A//api.decoprim.md/v1/items%3Fkey%3D3VG8BizGax&method=raw
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to connect to the https server from your local host.

You could set up ssl for you localhost by following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jonsamp/how-to-set-up-https-on-localhost-for-macos-b597bcf935ee)

Or you could keep it simple and use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Follow the instructions to install ngrok on your OS.

If you are using mac (assuming you have [brew](https://brew.sh/) installed)

```
brew install ngrok

ngrok http 3000 // port number your react app is running on.
```

You will get an https address which you can use to browse your app